# Optional isPresent vs orElse(null)

Tags: java, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I was updating the dependencies to Spring 5 in my project and was bombarded with compilation errors where the method definition of `findOne()` has been replaced by `findById()` which now returns an `Optional` (correct me if I am wrong).

While refactoring, I came across multiple approaches that I can choose to adopt, and I would therefore like some input on which one is to be preferred.

1st approach:

```
ExpectedPackage ep = expectedPackageRepository.findById(1).orElse(null);
if(ep != null){
    ep.setDateModified(new Date());
    expectedPackageRepository.saveAndFlush(ep);
}
```

2nd approach:

```
Optional<ExpectedPackage> ep = expectedPackageRepository.findById(1);
if(ep.isPresent()){
    ep.get().setDateModified(new Date());
    expectedPackageRepository.saveAndFlush(ep.get());
}
```

Or is there a third and better approach that I have missed? I went through several questions and a couple of articles, but I did not find a clear answer.

Comment: By the way, the `java.util.Date` class was supplanted years ago by `java.time.Instant`.

Comment: Neither. The whole purpose of `Optional` is to avoid `null`; the first does not do this and the second is bascially just `null` by another name.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can also do:

```
expectedPackageRepository.findById(1).ifPresent(
    ep -> {
        ep.setDateModified(new Date());
        expectedPackageRepository.saveAndFlush(ep);
    }
);
```

Ideally, you would also extract the part between brackets (`{}`) to a separate method. Then, you could write like this:

```
    expectedPackageRepository.findById(1).ifPresent(this::doSomethingWithEp);
```

Where:

```
void doSomethingWithEp(ExpectedPackage ep) {
    ep.setDateModified(new Date());
    expectedPackageRepository.saveAndFlush(ep);
}
```

You can read the documentation of `ifPresent` here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-

As it states, it will perform the specified action if the value is present and do nothing otherwise.

Comment: As Poger said. The great thig about ifPresent is you don't have to call the "dangerous" get method, instead teh value is presented to you.

Comment: is get() dangerous if you call it after checking the presence? am I missing something?

Comment: If you call `get()` immediately after a check to `isPresent()` then you should be fine. The method I presented just seems more clean in your case.

Comment: And if you apply correct transaction/session boundaries (with the @Transactional annotation, for example), then you don’t need to call the save method on the repository, making the code even simpler

Comment: Thanks Erwin for the tip, I will read up on it. Thanks Poger for a good answer.

Comment: @SadiqAli some people really really really really don't like get()

Comment: The rule of thumb is: avoid `isPresent` and `get`. This answer demonstrates that there are clearer alternatives, and that is most often the case (though not always).

Comment: @OleV.V. I'm not sure why you think `x.ifPresent(stuff)` is any clearer than `if(x.isPresent()) {stuff}`...

Answer (score 11):

Yes, there are other approaches.

If you absolutely expect there always to be a value, then use [`Optional::orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-) to throw an Exception if a null appears.

If you expect a null to possibly arrive, and have an alternative instance available as a fall-back option, use [`Optional::orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-).

If the fall-back instance is not on hand, but you have a function to call to provide a fall-back instance, use [`Optional::orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-).

If you don’t care about receiving a null, and want to do nothing when a null arrives, use [`Optional::ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-). Pass the block of code to be run if a value arrives.

If you only care if a value arrives that meets some requirement, use [`Optional::filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)). Pass a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) defining your requirement. For example, we care only if an `Optional< String >` contains text *and* that text has the word `purple` in it: `myOptional.filter( s -> s.contains( "purple" ) ).ifPresent( this::print ) ;`. If null received, our desired operation (a call to `print` in this example) never happens. If a value was received but failed to meet our predicate, our desired operation never happens.

---

Doing `if( myOptional.isPresent() ) { SomeClass x = myOptional.get() ; … }` is valid, and safe. But this is not the original intent of `Optional` as it is basically the same as doing an old-fashioned null-check `if ( null == x ) { … }`. The other methods on `Optional` provide a more clear and elegant way to express your intentions towards a possible null arriving.

Answer (score 7):

The other answer is basically some refactoring of your second approach, which has nothing wrong per-se, it's just a matter of style. Of course chaining and extraction to a separate method will make this a lot more readable and clear, no doubt (+1 from me), especially since the correct usage of `ifPresent`.

I'd just add here that `get`, well, was seen as somehow a design error ( or may be a bad method name, probably that came from `guava` mindset ). Using `get` even if it documented to throw an Exception when that value is missing is somehow weird ( if you think getters here, you would not expect a `getter` to throw an Exception). And you would not expect that `get` needs to be called *after* `isPresent`, at least not on the very first interactions with `Optional`.  Thus `get` was proposed to be deprecated ( and hopefully removed ), thus java-10 adds a better addition `orElseThrow()` - this makes sense right after you read it, cause the throwing part is in the name of the method, so no surprises.

Also, someone should tell you about that usage of `new Date()` that when used with `Optional` from java-8 just looks weird, there are much better time/date related classes already.

I am also not very sure why you are updating a modified date manually, when there are spring annotations for that like `PreUpdate/PrePersist`.

Comment: Brian Goetz has acknowledged that naming the `Optional::get` method was a mistake. Should have been named `Optional::getOrThrowSomeHorribleIfTheThingIsEmpty`. http://i.stack.imgur.com/LPg1Z.png

Answer (score 1):

you can also do:

```
Optional<ExpectedPackage> updatedPackage = expectedPackageRepository.findById(1).map(ep -> {
    ep.setDateModified(new Date());
    return expectedPackageRepository.saveAndFlush(ep);
});
```

Comment: @Boris `findById` returns `Optional` and `map` is the termination method. Please see the [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method of Optional: _If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it, and if the result is non-null, return an Optional describing the result. Otherwise return an empty Optional._