# How use findAny() and not return null

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-stream, option-type

I would like to know how I can use `findAny()` in a data stream when it does not find any coincidence, it does not return `null`.

```
String CountryFinal= "Spain";
List<ParContriesTO> listContries = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
listContries.add(new SelectItem(215, "Germany"));
Integer idCountry = (int) listContries.stream()
                    .filter(country -> country.getNoCountry().equals(CountryFinal))
                    .findAny().orElse(null).getCoCountry();
```

Comment: What you want to return then?

Comment: a) You're calling a method on something that could be `null` (because `orElse(null)`), which results in a NullPointerException rather than a `null` result. and b) you're casting the result to primitive `int` which can never be `null`.

Comment: @YCF_L really what I want to return for this case would be a 0 and for the case in which you want to filter an object?, I can not do inside the `orElse (new Object ())` ...?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Stream::findAny` returns [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) and its method `Optional::findAny`, according to the documentation, there are 4 ways to return `T`:

1. [`Optional::get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) returns the `T` or throws `NoSuchElementException`
2. [`Optional::orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) returns `T` or a default value
3. [`Optional::orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) returns `T` or a value provided with `Supplier`
4. [`Optional::orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-) returns `T` or throws a custom exception

As far as I understand, you are looking for the second or third method which returns a defined value in case the origin is `null`. You can return a null-object using the [Null-Object pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/null_object_pattern.htm) which represents an object which is valid but does "nothing". Or else you can use `null`.

I suggest you receive a country *before* you let return `null` or anything alse and use `getCoCountry()` method on it (I suppose `Country::getCoCountry` returns either `int` or `Integer`) - otherwise, what have you done would return `NullPointerException`.

Try the following snippet:

```
Integer idCountry = listContries.stream()               // Stream
    .filter(c -> countryFinal.equals(c.getNoCountry())) // Get one equals to "Spain"
    .findFirst()                                        // Get Optional<Country>
    .map(Country::getCoCountry)                         // If exists, get its code
    .orElse(0);                                         // Or else return an invalid code
```

Note there is no need to both filter by the country name and then check the equality since you expect there is only one `"Spain"`.

Comment: the most important one IMO is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047479/optional-ispresent-vs-orelsenull/52049465#52049465)

Comment: Indeed a nice overview of the diverse possibilities. `findAny` in general being better (no ordering to check). `int idC = listCountries.stream().filter(...).mapToInt(Country::getCoCountry).findAny().orElse(0);`

Answer (score 2):

The approach to invoke `getCoCountry` as last is generally bad.
What you could do is:

```
listContries.stream()
            .filter(country -> country.getNoCountry()
            .equals(CountryFinal))
            .findAny().map(Country::getCoCountry).orElse(WHATEVER_YOU_WANT);
```

To clarify: `findAny` returns `Optional` that may contain an instance of country. You can safely invoke `getCoCountry` in `map`. This is the importance of `Optional` type. At this step, you're still safe since you still have an `Optional` that MAY contain an `Integer` result. In the end, you can use `orElse` to decide what you want to have if instance is null.